# Add Array to multiple objects

Tags: objects, modifiers

I am trying to make a chain link fence. I created one of the links using four cylinders, but when I try to add the array to all four, it adds it to the last one I selected. Is there and way to use an array on the whole link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the modifiers from the active object to the selected objects with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>*> Modifiers*, or you can join all the cylinders into one object with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

In this case I would probably join them.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you could do that! I'm not that experienced with blender.